# My application server can't connect to my DB Cassandra server

Tags: php, cloud, cassandra

I have two servers. One has PHPCassa with a small app, the second has Cassandra install.

Here is the error I get:

An attempt was made to connect to every server twice, but all attempts failed. The last error was: TException:TSocket: Could not connect to ***.***.**.***:9160 (Connection refused [111])

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('phpcassa/lib/autoload.php');

use phpcassa\ColumnFamily;
use phpcassa\ColumnSlice;
use phpcassa\Connection\ConnectionPool;

$servers = array("***.**.***.***");
try {
    $pool = new ConnectionPool("test", $servers);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Erro with the connection!';
    echo $e->getMEssage();
}
echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($pool);
echo '</pre>';
    try {
            $column_family = new ColumnFamily($pool, 'test');
    } catch (Exception $e)
    {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    var_dump($column_family->get('a'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. Just need to change the **rpc_address** value from localhost to **0.0.0.0**.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#cant_listen_on_ip_any